# Android Studio not see LG G Pad 7.0 LTE

Tags: debugging, android-studio, lg

I have already turn on USB debugging  but Android Studio not seeded my device.
But other device (Samsung Galaxy S3) seeded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @ono

When device connected to PC with USB you must select connect mode:
Send images(PTP).

Other modes does not enable debugging.

Some modes does not enable debugging because try each one to getting success

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54806/lg-g2-debugging-mode-not-enabled/56674#56674?newreg=d773c808e11843ba9cbd8ce9e6e632d9